# Issue with Jmeter Constant throughput Sampler

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, throughput

I have Jmeter script with two thread group with two different API calls. My requirement is Thread Group 1 is to achieve 10 throughput per min and Thread Group 2 is to achieve 50 throughput per min. So I used constant throughput timer in the script.

[image]

When I run the test with above setting, thread group 2 is not achieving the expected throughput(50 per min) instead its only achieving the whatever the throughput defined in thread group 1's constant throughput timer(10 per min). I have kept 'this thread only" setting in the Timer.

Am I missing anything or some other setting needs to be done to achieve my requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two groups are having different threads but you have also used Interthread communication Pre and Post processor's which works on FIFO concept as shown below.

[image]

For more info check [this](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/InterThreadCommunication/?utm_source=jmeter&utm_medium=helplink&utm_campaign=InterThreadCommunication)

Until its FIFO you cant achieve it. Instead, use properties to set the variables and get them in other thread. Check [this](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/knit-one-pearl-two-how-use-variables-different-thread-groups).

Hope it help.